# How to show records with blank fields in crystal reports

Tags: null, crystal-reports, report, field

I have created a report that will show a "sales order number" and an "invoice number". I have created a link via the "sales order number". However, there are some sales orders that will not have an invoice number.

So whenever I add the field "invoice number" the records that do not have an invoice number do not appear.

How would I get these records to display. I have tried the report options of "converting data null values to default", I have also tried the formula:

```
If isNull ({vFM_INVOICE_DETAIL.InvoiceNumber}) THEN
"0"
else
{vFM_INVOICE_DETAIL.InvoiceNumber}
```

but I have not had any luck, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your link between both tables probably has a property "SQL join type". If you change that to "Left Outer" (when sales order **is** the left table), CR should query also sales orders w/o belonging invoices.

Comment: Thank you, however I tried the "left outer" option but crystal reports still will not show records of anything without a value.
The only way to get these records to display so far is to remove the field calling to the invoices

Comment: I'd recommend to verify first that left outer join in db query is working as expected, i.e. returns all desired rows. => Use CR function "show sql query" for that and test against db. Second, are you using any fields from the "right" table (= the one that may not have a value for all result rows = your invoice table) in filter formulas in CR (record or group filter)? If yes, it could be worth a try to change the order within this formula. Maybe you can post the whole formula here in this case.